# What causes "Reconnections made" statistics on network?

Tags: windows, networking

A client site is having hard-to-diagnose issues related to their network. While working on the problem, I ran the command "**net statistics workstation**" on one of the computers. I got the following data covering approximately a week of activity:

```
Bytes received                               23791085485
Server Message Blocks (SMBs) received        22410645
Bytes transmitted                            8962989188
Server Message Blocks (SMBs) transmitted     22410618
Read operations                              4481436
Write operations                             2275694
Raw reads denied                             0
Raw writes denied                            0

Network errors                               0
Connections made                             629
Reconnections made                           990560
Server disconnects                           40    

Sessions started                             0
Hung sessions                                0
Failed sessions                              0
Failed operations                            22
Use count                                    1212
Failed use count                             198
```

I'm thinking the very large number of "Reconnections made" (almost a million of them, so almost 2 per second for a week) should be telling me something about what's going on with this network. What precisely does that number represent and what does it indicate? How about the other numbers?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Redirector object in perfmon to get statistics about the Workstation service.  The descriptions of each counter in perfmon is a good place to start when you have no idea what they mean.

Directly from perfmon, here is the Microsoft description of "Reconnections Made" which is labelled as "Server Reconnects" in perfmon:

> Server Reconnects counts the number of times your Redirector has had
>   to reconnect to a server in order to complete a new active request. 
>   You can be disconnected by the Server if you remain inactive for too
>   long.  Locally even if all your remote files are closed, the
>   Redirector will keep your connections intact for (nominally) ten
>   minutes.  Such inactive connections are called Dormant Connections. 
>   Reconnecting is expensive in time.

Comment: Thank you! I figured there must be a more modern version of those statistics. Any idea what might cause the huge number of reconnects?

Comment: For comparison, I'm on a laptop over a shoddy VPN connection and I access network resources all the time, and my reconnections count is at 35. But also think of it this way, for you to be having that many reconnects makes me wonder why the client is trying to make so many connections in the first place. I can't think of any good reason. Maybe there's a bug on that client? Malware maybe?

Comment: Process Monitor should tell you what network connections the Workstation service is trying to make, and with 2 per second, they shouldn't be hard to find.